# C# parallel.For loop decreasing execution time

Tags: c#, json, multithreading, parallel.for

I found a osrm-machine and it returns a json string when i request. The json has some spesific information about 2 location and I am processing the json and getting the value of distance property for building distance matrix of these locations. I have more than 2000 location and this processing takes approximately 4 hours. I need to decrease the execution time with parallelism, but I am very new to the topic. Here is my work, what should I do for optimizing the parallel loop ? or maybe you can drive me to new approach. Thanks

```
 var client = new RestClient("http://127.0.0.1:5000/route/v1/table/");
            var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

            //rawCount = 2500
            Parallel.For(0, rowCount, i =>
            {
                Parallel.For(0, rowCount, j =>
                {
                    //request a server with spesific lats,longs
                    var request = new RestRequest(String.Format("{0},{1};{2},{3}", le.LocationList[i].longitude, le.LocationList[i].latitude,
                                                                                                        le.LocationList[j].longitude, le.LocationList[j].latitude));

                    //reading the response and deserialize into object
                    var response = client.Execute<RootObject>(request);

                    //defining objem with the List of attributes in routes
                    var objem = response.Data.routes;

                    //this part reading all distances and durations in each response and take them into dist and dur matrixes.
                    Parallel.ForEach(objem, (o) =>
                    {
                        dist[i, j] = o.distance;
                        dur[i, j] = o.duration;
                        threads[i,j] =  Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
                        Thread.Sleep(10);

                    });
                });
            });

        watch.Stop();
        var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

Comment: what purpose is the `Thread.Sleep(10)` serving?  If you want to slow down code, telling your threads to sleep will do the job, so that might be the problem here.

Comment: And nesting `Parallel.For` is probably not a good idea either. Way too much overhead. Just use it for the outermost loop.

Comment: What is the `Parallel.ForEach` supposed to do, writing information into *the very same* data storage in each iteration?

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned it up a bit. One use of parallelism is enough. There still is one loop that you need to look at, because it's overwriting data and I do not know what to do with it, that's your call.

You need to experiement with the `maxThreads` variable's value a bit. Normally, .NET would spin up enough threads so your processor can handle them, in your case you can spin up more because you *know* that all of them are just idling waiting for the network stack.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Process(int i, int j)
        {
            var client = new RestClient("http://127.0.0.1:5000/route/v1/table/");

            //request a server with spesific lats,longs
            var request = new RestRequest(String.Format("{0},{1};{2},{3}", le.LocationList[i].longitude, le.LocationList[i].latitude, le.LocationList[j].longitude, le.LocationList[j].latitude));

            //reading the response and deserialize into object
            var response = client.Execute<RootObject>(request);

            //defining objem with the List of attributes in routes
            var objem = response.Data.routes;

            //this part reading all distances and durations in each response and take them into dist and dur matrixes.

            // !!! 
            // !!! THIS LOOP NEEDS TO GO. 
            // !!! IT MAKES NO SENSE!
            // !!! YOU ARE OVERWRITING YOUR OWN DATA!
            // !!!
            Parallel.ForEach(objem, (o) =>
            {
                dist[i, j] = o.distance;
                dur[i, j] = o.duration;
                threads[i, j] = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            });
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

            var rowCount = 2500;
            var maxThreads = 100;

            var allPairs = Enumerable.Range(0, rowCount).SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Range(0, rowCount).Select(y => new { X = x, Y = y }));

            Parallel.ForEach(allPairs, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxThreads }, pair => Process(pair.X, pair.Y));

            watch.Stop();

            var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Im workin on mvc4 framework,i couldnt implement your approach. On the other hand there are some questions in my mind. You see over 2000x2000 (4m) iterations in loops. I want to divide for loop section into max threads, and each chuck should be only drived by 1 thread. so they are processing in the same time, and they must not override others' work.  How could i use parallel.for function for it? Also you said that, I am overriting datas in loop section. How ? Can you explain a little bit ? thanks

Comment: @EmreG Your loop will write data: `dist[i, j] = o.distance;`, but `i` and `j` don't change. All routes distances will be written into the same cell of your array. The last route wins. As to the rest of your questions: You should leave the parallelisation to `Parallel.ForEach` it's way more complicated than you know. With my solution you have one 2500*2500 loop and the .NET runtime decides how to make it run as fast as possible on your machine.